# Using & inside a for loop to automate matrix creation

Tags: matrices, loops

I want to make a command that fills a matrix with zeros. Here's how I thought it could work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % Math
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fillm}{+m +O{0}}{
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {0,...,\number\numexpr#1-2} { #2 &}
  #2
}

\begin{document}
 $$\begin{bmatrix} \fillm{5} \end{bmatrix}$$
\end{document}
```

If I change the `&` to a `\&`, the code complies and produces: [0&0&0&0&0]. This is great!

However, my true goal is for the code to produce: [0 0 0 0 0]. I want to actually use the & as they would be used in the matrix environment to space the zeros apart. If I remove the `\` and keep it as `&`, I get this error:

```
Incomplete \ifdim; all text was ignored after line 11.
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
Extra \fi.
Missing $ inserted.
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Not related but `$$` is discouraged syntax to start a displayed maths environment (it can lead to inconsistent spaces depending on line lengths), instead you should use `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: Would you be interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution? Or does it have to be based on `pgfplots`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you try to treat with `&` as with a token with catcode 4 in your macro. It works if the macro is processed outside the table item. But you tried to run your macro in the first item of the table. Then the token `&` has very specific behavior in such a case: it is not simply token: it ends the item data immediately and follows with tokens declared in the right part of the `\halign` preamble. For example:

```
\def\mymacro#1{\message{parameter is "#1"}}

\mymacro &               % prints: parameter is "&"

but:

\halign{a#b&c#d\cr 
   \relax \mymacro & \cr
}                        % prints: parameter is "b"
```

If there is not `\relax` in my example then the `\mymacro` is expanded without treating `&` as the end of the table item. It mans that if the `\myacro` occurs first (spaces are ignored) and it is fully expandable, then you can tread with `&` as with a token of category 4. This is the case of `\prg_replicate:nn` shown by egreg.

If you have a non fully-expandable macro then you can prepare the table data by the macro first outside the table and then you can run prepared data inside the table. For example:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\zeromatrix#1{\def\matrixbody{0}\tmpnum=1
    \loop \ifnum\tmpnum<#1\relax \addto\matrixbody{&0}\advance\tmpnum by1 \repeat
    \pmatrix{\matrixbody\cr}
}

$$
  \zeromatrix{5}
$$
```

But egreg showed more usable example especially for LaTeX usage (but without explanation where was the problem).

Answer (score 1):

A job for `\prg_replicate:nn` which repeats the tokens specified in the second arguments the number of times specified in the first argument.

The command `\zeromatrix{4}` builds a 4 times 4 zero matrix; you can add the number of rows as an optional argument like in `\zeromatrix[2]{4}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zeromatrix}{O{#2}m}
 {
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 }
   {
    0 \prg_replicate:nn { #2 - 1 } { & 0 } \\
   }
  \end{bmatrix}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\zeromatrix{3}\quad
\zeromatrix{4}\quad
\zeromatrix[2]{4}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It even works with `\zeromatrix{1}` that produces

[image]

If you prefer to specify the number of rows and optionally the number of columns (if the matrix is not square), you can change the code into

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zeromatrix}{mO{#1}}
 {
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 }
   {
    0 \prg_replicate:nn { #2 - 1 } { & 0 } \\
   }
  \end{bmatrix}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\zeromatrix{1}\quad
\zeromatrix{3}\quad
\zeromatrix{4}\quad
\zeromatrix{2}[4]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In either case, the trick is to use as default for the optional argument the value of the mandatory one.

Comment: Thank you so so much! :DDD This will be so useful in speeding up my work flow. It sounds like \ExplSyntaxOn allows \prg_replicate:nn  to work because \prg_replicate:nn  has a colon in its name?

Comment: Oh also, I didn't realize you could specify an argument's number in {}. That's so cool! If you want to supply an optional value and its number at the same time, can you not do that? I've seen +O{defaultvalue} before, so I'm wondering if you can do +O{defaultvalue, #argumentnumber}.

Comment: @MelodiCat guessed correctly, `\ExplSyntaxOn` has the effects to turn `_` and `:` into category letter (so you can use them in macro names), makes `~` a space, and normal spaces ignored.

Comment: @MelodiCat you understood that wrong, what `O{#2}` does is define an optional argument with the default value being the same value which was given to the second argument.

Comment: Also, is there a difference in NewDocumentCommand between +O and O?

Comment: Oh I see! This command defined above allows you to make square matrices or non-square matrices if you want to. Got it!

Comment: To check my understanding, would it be perfectly alright to put \ExplSyntaxOn inside the command rather than outside of it?

Comment: @MelodiCat No, it's not the same. It's like for `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. If you want to use the `expl3` functions (with `_` and `:`) to make a definition, `\ExplSyntaxOn` has to be in force at definition time. And you should remember that TeX never interprets what's in the body of a definition.

Comment: @MelodiCat in the argument specification of `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends the `+` means that the following argument can take an explicit `\par` token (or two consecutive blank lines) as part of its argument (so is defined `\long` in TeX-terminology).

Answer (score 1):

For information. The package `nicematrix` has commands to create matrices programmatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\bAutoNiceMatrix{2-2}{0}$\qquad $\bAutoNiceMatrix{4-4}{0}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]