# loop in tabular environment

Tags: tables, loops

I am trying to create a table depending on the size automatically. There is kind of a proliferation of loop commands in LaTeX, which makes it hard to figure out which one is suitable. I tried plain TeX loop and the loops from the packages `forloop`, `pgfloop` but I did not succeed.

Apparently, there is problem in running a loop inside a `tabular` environment.
I also tried to first run the loop and save output string into a `token` and then print the token inside the `tabular`. This works for some cases.

Here a minimal example: First, what I want to produce:

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
  1&2&3&4
\end{tabular}
```

Here, what I have tried with the TeX loop:

```
\newcounter{numofcol}\setcounter{numofcol}{4}
\newcounter{tmpcol}\setcounter{tmpcol}{1}

\begin{tabular}{|*{\thenumofcol}{c|}}
  \thetmpcol
  \loop
    \ifnum\value{tmpcol}<\value{numofcol}%
    \stepcounter{tmpcol}%
    &\thetmpcol
  \repeat
\end{tabular}
```

Apparently, the `&` symbol leads to problems in the loop. The same happens, if I use a loop from the packages `forloop` or `pgfloop`. The error is

```
ERROR: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \loop.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.140     &
           \thetmpcol
--- HELP ---
No help available
```

Hence I thought that I can save the string of the row in a `token` by

```
\newcounter{numofcol}\setcounter{numofcol}{4}
\newcounter{tmpcol}\setcounter{tmpcol}{1}
\newtoks\tmprowcontent

\tmprowcontent={x}
\loop%
\ifnum\value{tmpcol}<\value{numofcol}%
  \stepcounter{tmpcol}%
  \tmprowcontent=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\tmprowcontent & x}%
\repeat

\begin{tabular}{|*{\thenumofcol}{c|}}
  \the\tmprowcontent
\end{tabular}
```

This works if I don't include that counter in the `token`. If I replace `x` with the current counter value, i.e,

```
\newcounter{numofcol}\setcounter{numofcol}{4}
\newcounter{tmpcol}\setcounter{tmpcol}{1}
\newtoks\tmprowcontent

\tmprowcontent={\thetmpcol}
\loop%
\ifnum\value{tmpcol}<\value{numofcol}%
  \stepcounter{tmpcol}%
  \tmprowcontent=\expandafter{\the\tmprowcontent & \thetmpcol}%
\repeat

\begin{tabular}{|*{\thenumofcol}{c|}}
  \the\tmprowcontent
\end{tabular}
```

Then every entry is the last value of the counter, i.e, `4` in that case. This is because of the use of `\expandafter`. However, if I don't use `\expandafter`, then TeX tells me that it runs out of memory.

Hence, my question is how can I make this work?

Comment: Can you add how your actual table should look like? Maybe one of the existing table packages already has a feature for this and you don't have to manually create loops.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This is a minimal example. My actual settings for the tabular environment are more specified. I want to center the alignment in some cells and force them to have a minimal width. Nothing really special, but it distracts from the core of the problem. What environment can handle loops?

Comment: Maybe you don't need loops, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648886/36296 but if you don't share what kind of table you are trying to create, it is hard to give a recommendation.

Comment: With package `tabularray` and  `\UseTblrLibrary{functional}` you should find a solution see documentation page 58.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it is not like that I don't want to share. It is more that is might be complicated to transport what I want. I need access the changing counter. That why I said the solution with the `token` that I came up with is not enough. the example that I have presented perfectly displays the difficulty as far as I see. The reference to the zero matrix is interesting as it seems to use modern function, but it produces constant replicates and I need a loop that prints an ongoing counter.

Comment: @ManuelCart thanks, this looks interesting.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek If you need an ongoing counter, use the `counter` library of tabularray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the values, although you may need to hide the `&` so it is not seen too early and ends a table cell mid-test.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{numofcol}\setcounter{numofcol}{4}
\newcounter{tmpcol}\setcounter{tmpcol}{0}

\newcommand\foo{%
  \stepcounter{tmpcol}%
  \thetmpcol
  \ifnum\value{tmpcol}<\value{numofcol}\hiddenamp\expandafter\foo\fi}
\newcommand\hiddenamp{&}

\begin{tabular}{|*{\thenumofcol}{c|}}
  \foo
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also tried to hide the ampersand in a macro, which partially worked (I got no error), but for some reason the loop stoped early. Interesting that it works with a recursion but not with a loop and a `token`. Thank you!

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek loop macros are all implemented via recursion (there is no primitive loop in tex) but a table cell is a group so if the loop macro stores its state locally then it will get lost at the first `&`  here the only state is the global counter